# Dynamic filter and calculations from different tables?

Tags: dax, daxstudio

I am new to powerbi and looking forward to solve this table that I am trying to do.
I do have 3 tables and the example table is listed below.

***Users*** table is connected as **one to many** with ***product*** and ***tickets*** table

`Users` 1-----* tickets

`Users` 1-----* products

My issue is on the `Sales Amount` it will create for sure a **duplicate** amount of each product id. I am trying to create a measure that will get the distinct count of the **productid** and divide it to the sum of the Sales Amount if the productID is duplicated and those

The desired output is with the last table that I posted. which is dividing the duplicate of sales amount by the counts of duplicate and the rest will be the same.

Thank you so much in advance for the help!

Table 1
Users Table

```
Sales Rep      Owner ID
Mark           markid01
Joy            joy01
```

Table 2
product table

```
Ticket No.  product ID  Sales
XXX005474   productID1  $100 
XXX005475   productID2  $200 
XXX005476   productID3  $300 
XXX005477   productID4  $400 
XXX005478   productID5  $500 
XXX005479   productID6  $600 
XXX005480   productID7  $700
```

Table 3
Tickets

```
productTicket   ownerID
XXX005490   markid01
XXX005491   markid01
XXX005492   markid01
XXX005493   joy01
XXX005494   joy01
XXX005495   joy01
XXX005496   joy02
```

Selected columns in powerbi

```
Ticket No.  product ID      Owner ID   Sales Rep    Sales Amount      Output that I need 

XXX005474   productID34534  markid01    Mark        $32,400           $32,400 
XXX005475   productID00000  markid01    Mark        $100              $20
XXX005476   productID00000  markid01    Mark        $100              $20
XXX005477   productID00000  markid01    Mark        $100              $20
XXX005478   productID00000  markid01    Mark        $100              $20
XXX005479   productID00000  markid01    Mark        $100              $20
XXX005480   productID00001  markid01    Mark        $10,400           $10,400 
XXX005481   productID00002  markid01    Mark        $10,200           $10,200 
XXX005482   productID00003  markid01    Mark        $5,580            $5,580 
XXX005483   productID00004  markid01    Mark        $5,008            $5,008 
XXX005484   productID00005  markid01    Mark        $4,470            $4,470 
XXX005485   productID00006  markid01    Mark        $3,900            $3,900 
XXX005486   productID00007  markid01    Mark        $3,250            $3,250 
XXX005487   productID00008  markid01    Mark        $0                $0 
XXX005488   productID00009  markid01    Mark        $0                $0 
XXX005489   productID00010  markid01    Mark        $0                $0 
XXX005490   productID00011  markid01    Mark        $0                $0
```

Comment: Hi, would be possible your sample data is interconnected between each table?  What have you tried so far? Can you explain what is `Sales Amount`?

Comment: Thank you @AngeloCanepa for the response. I already got the formula and will share it here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Repeated_X = 

                Var vDuplicates = CALCULATE(
                COUNT('Demo Data'[product ID]), 
                     FILTER('Demo Data', 'Demo Data'[product ID] = EARLIER('Demo Data'[product ID])))
                Var vSales = 'Demo Data'[Sales]
                RETURN
                DIVIDE(vSales,vDuplicates)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).